# Retrieve data from service for specific customisation of a render

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new on react and currently developping a ionic4/react/stencil application.

My issue is this : I want to have a specific header for differents page of my app. For this, i created a "NavigationService" which load the current page.

export class NavigationService{

```
private pagesToDisplayWithMainHeader = ["app-project-gallery", "app-projects-gallery", "app-home", "app-documents"];

private currentPage : string;

public setCurrentPage(currentPage : string) : void{
    console.log("The current page is now : " + currentPage);
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
}

public whichIsTheHeaderToDisplay () : string{
    if (this.pagesToDisplayWithMainHeader.indexOf(this.currentPage)){
        console.log("Header is now: mainHeader");

        return "mainHeader";
    }

    else{
        console.log("Header is now: secondHeader");
        return "secondHeader";
    }
}
```

}

export const NavigationServiceData = new NavigationService();

For example, in my home page, i initialized the service like this :

```
constructor(){
NavigationServiceData.setCurrentPage("app-home");
```

}

Then in my app-title composant (which is personnalizing the header), i retrieve the name of the current app in the service.

if (NavigationServiceData.whichIsTheHeaderToDisplay() === "mainHeader") {
            return (

## Header 1

```
        );
    }

    else {

        return (

            <h1>Header 2</h1>

        );

    }
```

My App-title composant seems to not rendering. Should i use a State for my object currentPage? In this case, i don't know how to proceed because my Service isn't a parent of my app-title ...

Where i'm wrong ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Nb : I tried to use a global variable with window.currentPage, but same issue, my DOM of the app-title isn't rendering